# pandas Series dtype is datetime.date: How to plot

Tags: matplotlib, pandas

I have constructed a Series where the index type is DateTimeIndex, and the data type is `datetime.date`. I would like to plot dates vs dates, so that the nice date labels formatting applies to both the x axis and the y axis, and the line style would be points.

Calling `plot()` on the Serie yields this error

> No numeric data to plot

Comment: Can you provide some example data?

Comment: I had an open issue about this [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8113). Basically you'll need to use matplotlib.

Comment: Just a very trivial e.g. here: a pandas.Serie object, with index have 2 entries:  1 Aug 2014 and 2 Aug 2014 DateTimeIndex... and the the data for 1Aug2014 is 1Sep2014 and the data for 2Aug2014 is 2Sep2014, the data type being python's datetime.date